# Generate series of months in a column at postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, generate-series

In postgresql, how can I generate a series of monthly dates by the format 'YYYY-MM', with the oldest being the creation month of the user up to the current month?

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but I imagine it got down-voted because you didn't explain what you'd already tried/read, give your PostgreSQL version, or generally show much sign of making an effort on the question. In future please read the "better questions" section of http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql/info before posting. I've cancelled the downvote; unfair for a first-time user, just please read http://stackoverflow.com/help next time.

Answer (score 4):

something like :

```
select to_char(dt, 'YYYY-MM') 
from generate_series(
     date_trunc('month', (select created_at::date from users where id=1234)),
     now(), 
     '1 month'::interval) dt;
```

Comment: `date_trunc('day',created_at)` and `created_at::date` do the same thing. And you do not need to truncate a date at all.

Comment: Maybe `date_trunc('month',created_at)`?

Comment: No, just `generate_series((your subselect), current_timestamp, '1 month')`

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall' You need the date_trunc (with 'month'), because for example `generate_series('2013-01-10'::date, '2013-02-01'::date, interval '1 month')` returns just "2013-01-10 00:00:00+01", and you need 2 dates here.

Answer (score 1):

You can even do it in a single query level:

```
SELECT to_char(generate_series(created_at::date
                              ,now(), interval '1 mon'), 'YYYY-MM') AS month
FROM   users
WHERE  users_id = 123   -- users_id is unique
```